# how to insert and if defined for a variable in webstorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

suppose I have a code

```
var val = event.deltaX;
```

how can I auto insert a code which will transform the above into

```
if(event.deltaX)
{
x = event.deltaX;
}
```

Comment: didn't get it? what language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using live templates for this - see surround [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/simple-parameterized-and-surround-live-templates.html).